# RxSwift blockingGet equivalent

Tags: swift, repository-pattern, rx-swift

I'm developing a quite old application and need to handle between new rx way and old legacy threads. I started using repository pattern where all is emitted in Observables. And now I wanted to use my new repositories in old code. In RxJava it is quite simple, becuase I can use blockingGet() and my custom thread is waiting until something is produced or observable completes. I found that there is something like RxBlocking, but:

- One thing is that there is mentioned in documentation that it is developed for testing only and should not be used in production.
- I'm getting many crashes with EXC_BAD_ACCESS somewhere inside the .first() method.

Can you provide me some ideas how to handle the problem?

Comment: I think it would help if you gave a specific example.

Comment: It's hard to give a specific example, because this problem occurs in random places. When I'm saving context, or when I'm trying to change a property of my core data object.

Comment: Using RxBlocking like this feels _very_ wrong to me; however, without more specifics there's not much that can be said.

Answer (score 0):

I think, I found what was causing EXC_BAD_ACCESS. My operations were splitted between separated observables (ex I fetched data in one `toBlocking().first()` then I've modified the data and I saved them in the next one `toBlocking().first()`. When I merged everything in to one big observable combining my operation with `.map()` or `flatMap()` then everything started working properly.

I thought, that `persistntContainer.newBackgroundContext()` uses always the same thread, but when I checked that I noticed, that different threads are used for the `perform()` method.

Comment: That makes sense. RxBlocking is designed for testing. You wouldn't want independent tests to interfere with each other.